# SQL total quanity purchased by year

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

My last post was closed.

On the AdventureWorks2012 database, I have to write a query using the Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail table and list the **total quanity purchased for each product during 2006** and label sum as TotatQtyPurchased. I also have to group by ProductID.

Here is my lastest query

```
SELECT POD.ProductID, POD.ModifiedDate, 
       SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQtyPurchased 
       FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD  
       GROUP BY POD.ProductID  
       HAVING ModifiedDate = '2006'
```

But I get this error.

Column 'Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail.ModifiedDate' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is very frustrating.

UPDATE:  When I am trying to specify the date "2006" for my query,  I always get a blank execution (i.e. no rows or columns) whenever I type the following commands:

WHERE ModifiedDate LIKE '2006%'
or
WHERE ModifiedDate = '2006'

Comment: The error message is very clear. You have to include the `POD.ModifiedDate` in your column list, because it's not part of an aggregate column (one obtained with `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, or `MAX`). A search here on the exact error message "Column is invalid in the having clause" will find you many examples and explanations of how to fix it. The first thing you should always do is search for the error message; odds are very high you're not the first one to see it (or ask about it here).

Comment: When you have a query with an aggregate function (Sum), you need to 'group by' every field that you're returning unless its also an aggregate function.  So you'll need to group by ModifiedDate too it looks like

Comment: Minor point, but are you sure you want to use ModifiedDate, as opposed to OrderDate or ShipDate?

Comment: I want to use OrderDate

Answer (score 4):

You are close, and most SQL error messages tell you exactly what the error is, it takes a bit of practice to interpret them.

- Take out the HAVING clause for now...
- Do a bit of research on the WHERE clause, figure out how the WHERE
  can be used instead of HAVING...

Since this is homework, I don't want to give you the answer, but this should get in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anything in Having Clause, you need to use aggreagte function. For example,
You could use like this

```
HAVING MAX(MODIFIEDDATE) = '2006'
```

But from your problem it looks like, WHERE clause will solve your problem best.If the above query result set is you need, then,

```
SELECT POD.ProductID, MODIFIEDDATE, SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQtyPurchased 
       FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD  
       WHERE ModifiedDate = '2006'
       GROUP BY POD.ProductID, MODIFIEDDATE
```

I made the edit, what i would suggest is, since you are using Modified date in WHERE clause you don't need to specify that in SELECT clause.

Comment: I keep getting this error message: Column 'Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail.ModifiedDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. On a somewhat related question, I did a similar query and managed to execute it sucessfully: SELECT POD.ProductID, POD.ModifiedDate, 
       SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQtyPurchased 
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD
GROUP BY POD.ProductID, POD.ModifiedDate
ORDER BY ModifiedDate ASC

Comment: Will give the same error, since you still have ModifiedDate in the select statement but not the group by

Comment: @sgmoore Thanks overlooked that. Modified Now

Comment: thank you.  the query now is successfully, but I only want to return dates from 2006 and exclude 2005, 2007, & 2008.  SELECT POD.ProductID, POD.ModifiedDate, 
       SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalQtyPurchased 
       FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail POD  
       GROUP BY POD.ProductID, POD.ModifiedDate
    HAVING MAX(MODIFIEDDATE) = '2006'

Comment: You need to read up on the difference between `where` and `having`. What your latest query is doing is adding up the quantities for each product/date (regardless of year) and then selecting those products where were last modified in 2006. Santhosh's query is correctly selecting only those modified in 2006 **before** grouping and summing.

Comment: Santhosh's query was executed properly, but 0 rows were affected.  In other words, the rows and columns are blank.  I typed in the query exactly as it was stated.

Comment: Do you have rows for that condition? What is the format and datatype in the date column

Comment: ModifiedDate is probably a date/datetime, so you may need `where year(modifiedDate) = 2006`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited now**

Try this

```
SELECT POD.ProductID, POD.ModifiedDate, SUM(Order_qty)
AS TotalQtyPurchased FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail  POD  where ModifiedDate = '2006' GROUP BY 
POD.ProductID
```

Comment: didn't work.  Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'PurchaseOrderDetail'.